# Connections in /proc/[pid]/net/tcp which don't appear in /proc/net/tcp

Tags: networking, proc, socket

I'm implementing code to fetch all network connections and associate them with the PIDs using them.

Say, for tcp4, for each pid, I'm listing `/proc/pid/fd`, searching there for links to sockets, reading their inode numbers and looking them up in `/proc/net/tcp` to get the details about the connection.

However, if I look up the inode numbers in `/proc/net/tcp` I get *less* connections than if I look them up in `/proc/[pid]/net/tcp`. For example, if I'm doing the above process while relying on `/proc/net/tcp`, I can only see sockets opened by my browser, while if I'm relying on `/proc/[pid]/net/tcp`, I can see that my broswer and the 'java' process have open connections.

So should I rely on `/proc/net/tcp` or `/proc/[pid]/net/tcp` for this purpose? I'm confused because psutil, which is a widely-used package in Python is using `/proc/net/tcp` on the one hand, but it seems like some connections are missing if I don't look at `/proc/[pid]/net/tcp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/net` is a symbolic link to `/proc/self/net`, so `/proc/net` and `/proc/[pid]/net` are different only when process `[pid]` and the process which examines `/proc/net` are in different [network namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html).

If you want to list all the sockets, you'll have to look through all the namespaces; for two processes which are in the same network namespace, their `/proc/PID/ns/net` will have the same inode number. That way you can enumerate all the different network namespaces on your system.