# How to get unix socket inode given its path?

Tags: linux, proc, socket, inode

Let `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock/` be an open socket. I can `stat` it to get inode of the **file** (here **1200**)

```
# stat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  File: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 17h/23d Inode: 1200        Links: 1
Access: (0777/srwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  109/   mysql)   Gid: (  121/   mysql)
Access: 2020-08-24 07:06:50.716419994 +0200
Modify: 2020-07-20 14:51:30.892060665 +0200
Change: 2020-07-20 14:51:30.892060665 +0200
```

However, what I want is not the disk filesystem inode (ext4 or similar), but OS socket inode as reported in `/proc/net/unix` (**4517115**):

```
# grep mysqld.sock /proc/net/unix
ffff9efa85f1bc00: 00000002 00000000 00010000 0001 01 4517115 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

The question is, given filesystem socket inode (**1200**), how can I retrieve OS socket inode (**4517115**)? Unfortunately, I can rely on neither `ss`, `lsof`, or even `/proc/net/unix` as those sources are unreliable when the socket file has been created (for example) by a container:

- ss, lsof and others often do not list these sockets at all (maybe those tools rely on `/proc/net/unix`?),
- `/proc/[pid]/net/unix` is unreliable as it may be impossible (or at least hard) to match a file mapped from host to a different path in container. Furthermore, `/proc/net/unix` itself might not list these sockets.

Comment: if the problem is related to using namespaces, the solution must rely on namespaces. Why would an other tool work better than `ss` in the wrong (namespace) environment?

Comment: You can't. Everytime you listen() on a unix socket, you get a different inode. Everytime you (successfully) connect to a unix socket, you get a different inode. Everytime you accept() a connection on a unix socket, you get a different inode. Neither is related to the on-disk inode. On Linux, you can get them from the target of `/proc/<pid>/fd` (the number from `socket:[num]`).

Comment: ss and other tools don't use `/proc/net` -> `/proc/self/net` they get their info via unix_diag netlink sockets (a newer interface). Use `/proc/pid-from-other-net-namespace/net/unix` or run `ss`, etc via `nsenter` if you want to gather info from other containers.

Comment: @pizdelect Yeah, I'm currently using `nsenter` + `/proc/self/net/unix` + `stat` on the file listed there to do that. It's slow though as I do that for every PID in the host /proc/.

Comment: You don't have to do it for every pid; only for every network namespace. [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546122/313992)

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather done for every <mount, network> namespace combination?

Comment: Note that `ss` doesn't seem to work. Running `ss` from within the container that created the socket file reports no sockets.